# Get ElementRef from component instance

Tags: angular, elementref

On my Angular library I have a code similar as below:

test.component.html:

```html
<third-party-component #tpComponent></third-party-component>
<my-component [tp-component]="tpComponent"></my-component>
```

my-component.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ThirdPartyComponent } from '@3rd/party-library';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('tp-component') tpComponent: ThirdPartyComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tpComponent.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I am looking for a way, if there is any, to access the `ElementRef` from the `ThirdParyComponent` instance passed as the `@Input` property - unfortunately I can't change the `ThirdParyComponent` to expose its own `ElementRef`.

PS: I know I can create a method on `MyComponent` to set both the `ThirdParyComponent` instance and its `ElementRef`, but I would like to simplify this with the `@Input`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: can you show whats not working here?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmxx5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts check this link

Comment: Hey @GaurangDhorda, tks. But actually I need both instances, the component's and the `ElementRef`'s from the component.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526536/get-elementref-from-component-instance?answertab=active#tab-top but I wanted to do  with one `@Input` property.

Comment: by passing input reference of `tp-component` to `my-component` , You can get Element ref directly from my-component, I do not think you need seperate input for this. as i have done in my stackblitz link you can check it out.

Comment: But I want the `ElementRef` of the instance as well, in your example I just only have the component instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component housing both `third-party-component` and `my-component`, can you do:

```
@ViewChild('tpComponent') tpComponentElementRef: ElementRef;
....
<my-component [tp-component]="tpComponent" 
              [tp-component-elementRef]="tpComponentElementRef"></my-component>
....
@Input('tp-component') tpComponent: ThirdPartyComponent;
@Input('tp-component-elementRef') tpComponentElementRef: ElementRef;
```

Something like this?

Comment: This is an option, I was looking for something simpler that didn't require the user to use a `@ViewChild` to send me the component's instance and the `ElementRef`. But I think I will go that way if there isn't other.

Comment: I resolved to follow the above approach, I don't think there is a bullet proof way to get the `ElementRef`only with the component instance. Thanks for the help.